# XSLT xmlns on root only

Tags: xslt-1.0

Want to add an xmlns declaration to the root only and I use this xml:

```
<Message>
</Message>
```

and xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:element name="Element1" namespace="http://www.blablabla.com">
<xsl:element name="Element2">
<xsl:element name="Element3">Hmm</xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="Element4">
</xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
<Element1 xmlns="http://www.blablabla.com">
<Element2 xmlns="">
<Element3>Hmm</Element3>
</Element2>
<Element4 xmlns=""/>
</Element1>
```

I want only Element1 to have xmlns not the Element2, 4 or others.

I can make this way but that means to write for each element the variable name:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNS"
  select="'http://www.blablabla'"/>


<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:element name="Element1" namespace="{$vNS}">
<xsl:element name="Element2" namespace="{$vNS}">
<xsl:element name="Element3" namespace="{$vNS}">Hmm</xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="Element4" namespace="{$vNS}">
</xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `xsl:element` with namespaces requires you to indicate for all elements in which namespace they belong. It is easier to avoid using `xsl:element` when dealing with namespaces.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:bla="http://www.blablabla.com">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <bla:Element1>
            <Element2>
                <Element3>Hmm</Element3>
            </Element2>
            <Element4 />
        </bla:Element1>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will create the required namespace on only the first element. You just have to declare the namespace into the stylesheet declaration and then you can use this namespace directly in the elements. Also your XSLT is more readable when avoiding `xsl:element`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did change your code a bit.               `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.blablabla.com">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Element1>
            <Element2>
                <Element3>Hmm</Element3>
            </Element2>
            <Element4 />
        </Element1>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: You changed the namespace declaration in the stylesheet to a default namespace `xmlns="http://www.blablabla.com"`. Which means all elements without a namespace prefix will be part of that default namespace. That is quite different than your question of only set a namespace on the first element. Just to note...

Comment: Still only the first element has xmlns. If I run my code this is what I get: `<Element1 xmlns="http://www.blablabla.com">
<Element2>
<Element3>Hmm</Element3>
</Element2>
<Element4/>
</Element1>`

Comment: While running yours this: `<bla:Element1 xmlns:bla="http://www.blablabla.com">
<Element2>
<Element3>Hmm</Element3>
</Element2>
<Element4/>
</bla:Element1>`. I think my question wasn't very clear in the first place. In the end I did get what I was looking for. Thanks again for sharing your solution.