# XSL add namespace definition to XML root only

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'd like to add a default namespace definition to the root element using `XSL`. Problem is however, that after `XSL` transformation, the subelement has attribute `xmlns=''` which I need to prevent.

**XML Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog>
      <changeSet author="abc" id="def">
...
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

**Expected XML Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><databaseChangeLog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">
      <changeSet author="abc" id="def">
...
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I've tried with **XSL** like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/databaseChangeLog">
        <databaseChangeLog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </databaseChangeLog>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"> 
            <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**but result is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><databaseChangeLog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">
      <changeSet xmlns="" author="abc" id="def">
...
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Please note, there is a similar question: [XSLT xmlns on root only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627884/xslt-xmlns-on-root-only), however in my case there are many more elements included (as just those listed in sample) in the XML, so it's not feasible for me.

Comment: Note that in your expected output, `xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"` creates a _default namespace_ for all child elements of `databaseChangeLog`. So, it is not really a namespace for the "root only".

Comment: @MathiasMüller: thanks for correction, feel free to update question/title

Comment: With your permission, I added a clarification to your question. The question title looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: But then you are not copying text (and other nodes that are neither element nor attribute).

Comment: i only asked the OP to change a specific template.

Comment: True, but that template copied text. The changed template doesn't.

Comment: Works fine, text is copied by default. That is, I tested `<changeSet author="abc" id="def">text in here</changeSet>` , output was the same. If I am not mistaken, `comment()` and `processing-instruction()` are no longer matched.

Comment: I am sorry, I wasn't quite clear. The text is now copied by the default template. Before the change, the text was copied by the template matching node(). The same template also copied comments and processing instructions. These are no longer copied after the change is made. This may make no difference to the OP - but it should be pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that with XSLT, you don't create namespace declarations. Rather, you create elements with the right expanded name (namespace URI plus local name), and the serializer looks after getting the namespace declarations right. So you want the changeSet element to be in namespace http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog, you have to create it in that namespace, you can't just put a default namespace declaration on its parent element. If you create the changeSet element in a different namespace from its parent, the serializer will add a namespace declaration to reflect your (apparent) intent.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <databaseChangeLog 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </databaseChangeLog>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()|comment()|processing-instruction()" >
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```